# How can I disassemble or decompile a C++ executable?

Tags: software-recommendation, c++

Is there any tool like Dumpbin (for Windows) in Ubuntu which can disasssemble (produce machine code) for an executable file?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks I found that `objdump` can also do the good job.I will check you link.  +1 for that:)
Regards
softy

Comment: Congratulation on solving your question, please mark your answer as accepted sonother can benefit